# Storing a React element in Redux state: anti-pattern?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Is it advisable or even possible to include a React element in a Redux store's state? Since it is a plain object describing "what should be drawn", I guess it should be safe, but still: any experience out there?

*Why would I want to do such a thing?* I'm writing an abstract React component capable of embedding other components, described elsewhere in the React tree. This would allow them, for instance, to escape from the physical boundaries of a hardware-accelerated, CSS-`transform`ed DOM node, used for performance.

Comment: Yes. The state should be serialisable.

Comment: Actually React elements are not serializable because of `$$typeof` which holds a `Symbol`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes - as with many other similar ideas, it's *possible*, but is absolutely an anti-pattern because it breaks the ability to do things like time-travel debugging (one of Redux's core selling points). See the Redux FAQ at http://redux.js.org/docs/FAQ.html#organizing-state-non-serializable for further details.

Now, keeping React component classes in a React component's internal state is different, and might be useful for cases like dynamically requiring a component and re-rendering once the implementation has been downloaded.

Comment: It does break persistence/hydration (haven't tested that, since I don't need it), but not time travel. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yprpq1cu/4/) -- can't check time travel inside jsfiddle (Redux DevTools don't work there), but it does work locally.